# PHP: Upload csv and convert special characters to HTML

Tags: php, character-encoding

```
if(!empty($_FILES['csv'])){
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $text = file_get_contents($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);
        header('Content-type: application/CSV');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $_FILES['csv']['name']);
        echo $text;
        return;
}
```

I have no problem uploading the file and then spitting it back out again as you can see above... but I need to convert special characters like accent characters and em-dashes into either a equivalent or the HTML version. How might I do that?

Windows 7, Apache 2.2.21, PHP 5.4.3, CakePHP 1.3

Comment: ended up using this (somewhat dirty) function found at http://alanwhipple.com/2011/06/04/php-clean-encoding-issues-smart-curly-quotes-em-dashes/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the function [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

From what I know you might just change your `echo` output to

```
echo htmlentities($text);
```

Don't forget to look at the available flags [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), it allows some fine tuning depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function:

```
$text = htmlentities(file_get_contents($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']));
```

To reverse this, if you need to at any point, use [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).